# What's wrong with my query?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List<Product2> getProduct2(List<String> Ids) {

    system.debug('productsetids' + Ids);
    Set<String> filterIds = new Set<String>();
    for(String s : Ids){
        filterIds.add(s);
    }

    system.debug('filterids' + filterIds);
    List<Product2> products = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id =:filterIds];

    System.debug('returnedproducts' + products );
    return products;


}
```

productsetids and filterIds are filled but the SOQL query returns empty, the ids are valid in the system with corresponding products.

Comment: Can the running user see/access those records?

Comment: I can get returned records from running SOQL query on dev console. Running user is also admin.

Comment: Just to be sure it's not an issue with your Ids, can you show us one of the Ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be sending a stringified list with 1 member and ids separated with commas. Use debug to check the list size.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have constructor in Apex `Set` to convert `List` to `Set` directly. You can use like below:

```
Set<String> filterIds = new Set<String>(Ids);
```

You need not iterate over list for getting Set.

This method should definitely work. Can you check

1. If you are definitely passing correct `Product2` Ids and whether its `List` because I have seen implementations where you pass `String` of comma separated Ids but expect `List` of Ids - this will not happen.
2. If above is fine, do you have access to those Products ?

Comment: Run system.debug('productsetids size' + Ids.size()); to make sure your ids are not just under index 0 (size 1). This is likely the issue as you stated you and the running user are Sys Admins.

Answer (score 0):

you are using "=:" but it should be "in :" like following :

```
 List<Product2> products = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id in :filterIds];
```

"=:" is used to compare only one id and you are using list so "in :".

Comment: That is certainly not true. `=` works with `Set` as well

Comment: `List<String> Ids` is a string list and I can query ids with the set right?